# How to upload a variable amount of files using a single multipartform post header key

Tags: python, http-post, multipartform-data, cherrypy, voluptuous

I have a repeatable form field:

```
<div class="repeat">
    <input type="file" name="files[==row-count-placeholder==]" />
</div>
```

that will (using jQuery) for example result in

```
<div class="repeat">
    <input type="file" name="files[0]" />        
    <input type="file" name="files[1]" />  
    <input type="file" name="files[2]" />
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

according to how many files want to be uploaded by the user. The forms method is `post`and enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

Using cherrypy as my server and voluptuous validation library I would like to save the uploaded files:

```
import voluptuous

def save_uploaded_file(file, path)
    #save file on server...

def validate_files(files):    
    for file in files:
        save_uploaded_file(file, cherrypy.request.config['static_dir'])

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, **kwargs):

    schema = Schema({
        'files' : validate_files
    }, required = True, extra = True)

    kwargs = schema(kwargs)
```

Therefore I would actually need a post header that contains information for all the files (best would be something like a list of the files) according to **one key** called `files`, but all I get is multiple keys such as `files[0]`, `files[1]` and so on...

How do I approach this? Do I somehow have to manually create an array that contains all the `files` information or is there a more common or practical way to do it?

**Solution (following saaj's suggestion):**

```
schema_dict = {
    'name' : All(Length(min=3, msg="Can't believe that there is a name less than 3 characters...")),
    # ...
    }

# validate files
isPart = lambda v: isinstance(v, cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part)      
files1 = [a for a in kwargs.values() if isPart(a)]
files2 = [a for a in cherrypy.request.params.values() if isPart(a)]
assert files1 == files2

for file in files1:
    # for each file add dict entry and route to validation function
    schema_dict.update({file.name : validate_file}) 

schema = volu.Schema(schema_dict, required = True, extra = True)
```

Like this a `Schema` can obviously contain many other fields. Submitted files are being added generically to any `Schema`. Cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take file parts from request (if your form doesn't contain other types of parts you can take request's params as is).

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self, **kwargs):
  isPart = lambda v: isinstance(v, cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part)
  files1 = [a for a in kwargs.values() if isPart(a)]
  files2 = [a for a in cherrypy.request.params.values() if isPart(a)]

  assert files1 == files2
  print(files1) # pass it where you want to
```

Related CherryPy questions: [upload performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13002676/2072035), [asynchronous upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26876695/2072035).